# Invoke a block from a template file with arguments

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have written a custom module which creates a block. I invoke the block from a template file using the following code.

```
$block = module_invoke('my_mod', 'block_view', 'block_1a', $an_argument);
print $block['content'];
```

I need to access `$an_argument` in the module when the block is created.

How can I access the argument I pass to the block when it's invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would have to implement the hook_block_view to handle your argument.

[The api docs for hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)